# Remove special characters from a string in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

The field contains special characters like pipe,returns ,* and (
example:

```
Table Name: Employee
Field names: id, name
ID   Name
01   Radhika N (MBA)*MCA*
02   Venu (BBA)
03   (MBA)Ananth
04   Visal **MCA**
```

Now i want a select statement that removes all special characters and my result should be

```
ID   Name
01  RADHIKA N
02  VENU
03  ANANTH
04  VISHAL

Select id, upper(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(name,'|',' '),chr(10),' '),chr(13),' '),chr(9),' '), chr(42), ' '), chr(40), ' ')) as NAME
from employee
```

this will take out any ascii special characters and *
But the result was:

```
ID   Name
01  RADHIKA N (MBA) MCA
02  VENU (BBA)
03  (MBA) ANANTH
04  VISHAL MCA
```

How do i remove "(MBA)" from the names?

Comment: No, that wasn't the result. The letters between \* ... \* should still be there also, where did they go?  Then: what is the assignment? You started with "remove special characters" (even in your title), but it seems your assignment is different. Surely M, B, A are not "special characters". Please formulate your problem more carefully / more meaningfully.

Comment: Yes, i have edited my question, the result had the letters between *...*.
in the portion of (MBA) , M, B, A are not special characters but they are within the parenthesis ( ) which is a special character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sample data shown, the query below would work.

```
select trim(upper(regexp_replace(name,'[\(|\*](.*)[\)|\*]','')))
from tbl
```

Comment: Your suggestion helped. Thank you. 
I used;

select id,  upper(replace(replace(replace(replace(trim(regexp_replace(name,'[\(|\*](.*)[\)|\*]','')),'|',' '),chr(10),' '),chr(13),' '),chr(9),' ')) as name 
from employee

this gave me the desired results.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `regexp_replace()`.  I would approach this in two steps:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(name, '[(][A-Z]+[)]', ''), '[^a-zA-Z ]', '')
```

The first removes the part in parentheses.  The second keeps only alpha-numeric values.

Comment: This resulted in :
ID   Name
01  RADHIKA N MBA) MCA
02  VENU BBA)
03  MBA) ANANTH
04  VISHAL MCA